# max execution time error handling

Tags: php, error-handling

I have one script that sometimes gives Max execution times reached error. This is normal, not this a problem. The problem is that in this case I would write specific error message.
How do i do this?

Comment: you should work on your acccept rate, to motivate some people to answer you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function say_goodbye() {
   if (connection_aborted()) {
      //  Perform some action if user has aborted the transaction
   } elseif (connection_status() == CONNECTION_TIMEOUT) {
      //  perform some other action if the connection has timed out
   } else {
      //  any normal completion actions
   }
}

register_shutdown_function("say_goodbye")
```

You can also pass parameters to the shutdown function

Answer (score 1):

Use `set_error_handler`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php