# PHP Max Exection Timeout Notification

Tags: php

Is it possible to get Max Execution timeout notification so that i can use code clean up operations before the php script stops running?

Basically, i am trying to create a script that can do some changes/modifications to my database which has huge data pile. Also, this php script execution can be paused/resumed using a filelock.

Comment: possible duplicate of [max execution time error handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156093/max-execution-time-error-handling)

Answer (score 1):

You can either use [`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) or [`register_shutdown_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php).

**Edit:** See also:  [max execution time error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156093/max-execution-time-error-handling)

Comment: Is it possible to restart the script from the function that we have used in register_shutdown_function()

Comment: Not really.  If you want to continue doing something, why not just do `set_time_limit(0)` so it can run indefinitely?

Comment: I tried using set_time_limit(0) but it is not working. The script stops at some point.

Comment: I assure you that it does work.  Either you are in safe mode, or something else is stopping your script.  Checked your memory usage to make sure you aren't exceeding limits?  What exactly is the error.  Don't try to hack around this... fix the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you set 0 to set_time_limit, it will never stop :)

You can increase the limit time inside your code using:

```
set_time_limit(300); //time in seconds
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

or

changing the max_execution_time parameter inside your php.ini.

The default time is 30 seconds.